# How to override __add__ properly in this case?

Tags: python

The class `Link` is used to build and manipulate linked lists:

```
class Link:
    """A linked list with a first element and the rest."""
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i == 0:
            return self.first
        else:
            return self.rest[i-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return 1 + len(self.rest)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string that would evaluate to self."""
        if self.rest is Link.empty:
            rest = ''
        else:
            rest = ', ' + repr(self.rest)
        return 'Link({0}{1})'.format(self.first, rest)
```

By mimicking `__repr__` I want to implement an `__add__` function:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if self is Link.empty:
        return other
    else:
        return Link(self.first, add(self.rest, other))
```

However it doesn't work and gives me such an error (The actual file path is hidden):

```
>>> lst =  Link(3, Link(4, Link(5)))
>>> lst 
Link(3, Link(4, Link(5)))
>>> lst + lst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PATH_TO_THE_FILE", line 31, in __add__
    return Link(self.first, add(self.rest, other))
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

So I changed the last line of `__add__` to:

```
return Link(self.first, self.rest.__add__(other))
```

and this time the error becomes:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Link") to tuple
```

Then I deleted the `__add__` method in the class and tried another way:

first add the following function to the module:

```
def extend_link(s, t):
    if s is Link.empty:
        return t
    else:
        return Link(s.first, extend_link(s.rest, t))
```

and in the terminal:

```
>>> lst =  Link(3, Link(4, Link(5)))
>>> Link.__add__ = extend_link
>>> lst + lst
Link(3, Link(4, Link(5, Link(3, Link(4, Link(5))))))
```

So why `Link.__add__ = extend_link` works but overriding `__add__` in the class doesn't?

PS: the example is from [here](http://www.composingprograms.com/pages/29-recursive-objects.html)

Comment: What's `add`? It's clearly complaining about missing `add` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you get is due to the fact that `add` does not exist.

You override `__add__` in your class, which corresponds to overriding the `+` operator. Therefore, `add(self.rest, other)` should only be `self.rest + other`.

The `+` operator works by looking for the `__add__` method of the left member, and calling it if it exists. That is why `self.rest.__add__(other)` works as well. However, the reason to redefine `__add__` is to be able to use `+` directly, so `__add__` should never be called under this name.

Now, the second error you get is a bit trickier. It clearly states that you are trying to add a `Link` instance and a `tuple` instance, which is not defined. A bit of investigation lead me to the fact that at one point, `self.rest` is equal to `empty`. But `empty` is defined as `()` which is a `tuple`.

The easiest fix to this is to check in your `__add__` definition if one of the members is equal to `empty`, and return the right result, **without** calling `+`. This is what you did in your `extend_link` function.

A better fix would be to build your `empty` so as to make it a `Link` instance.